# Why Prefix N' Not working with input parameters?

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, prefix

Look at this code in `MS SQL Server`:

```
DECLARE @Search NVARCHAR(200)='TEST1,TEST2';

SELECT C1 FROM dbo.StrToTable(@Search)
```

As you seen `@Search` is Unicode but I need something like:

```
SELECT C1 FROM dbo.StrToTable(N'TEST1,TEST2')
```

How can I use `prefix N'` for a Variable in SQL?

Comment: Tried it, works as expected. What do you mean by it not working?

Comment: Something like: `code`SELECT C1 FROM dbo.StrToTable(N @Search)`code`

Comment: The search variable is already in unicode though. Your question does not convey the real problem you are having. Please [edit] your question and clarify the problem you are encountering. A small script that reproduces the problem would be desirable.